# moment.js - display either date OR time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

On a page that I'm building, there is a requirement to either display the date (eg: 15 Aug) or, if the date is today, just display a time, eg: 10pm.

What would be the best way of coaxing that behaviour out of moment.js?

The format i'd like for a date is 'd MMM' and the format for time would be 'hA' (if minutes are 0) or 'h:mmA' (if minutes are not 0).

Any ideas on how to approach this? It looks like the calendar() function might be able to support something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use [moment.calendar](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/): set everything except `sameDay` to *d MMMM* and `sameDay` to *h:mmA*. You can't do finer grain than that.

```
function timeTodayDateElse(date){
    moment.lang('en', {
        'calendar' : {
            'lastDay' : 'D MMMM',
             'sameDay' : 'h:mmA',
            'nextDay' : 'D MMMM',
            'lastWeek' : 'D MMMM',
            'nextWeek' : 'D MMMM',
            'sameElse' : 'D MMMM'
       }
    });

    return moment(date).calendar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the conclusion that I came to as well!

Comment: Well, actually, you could do an if statement that checks if the date is today using moment.diff (see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) and if it isn't use `calendar`, otherwise use your *hA* format.

Comment: Those lowercase d's should be uppercase D's (otherwise it will display the day of the week instead of the month).

Answer (score 8):

You could write a micro plugin to do this yourself.

```js
moment.fn.formatTimeToday = function () {
    var now = moment(),
        format = "d MMM";
    if (this.date() === now.date() && 
        Math.abs(this.diff(now)) < 86400000) {
        // same day of month and less than 24 hours difference
        if (this.minutes() === 0) {
             format = "hA";
        } else {
             format = "h:mmA";
        }
    }
    return this.format(format);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search (moment.js relative time) gives [this link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) to the documentation. You should be able to customize this with the format strings you want.

Comment: Thanks, the relative time was close but the calendar function was more suitable for me.